# Conditionally allow rotation on iOS 8

Tags: ios8

On iOS 8, apps like Weather and Clock rotate on the iPhone 6 Plus but not on the smaller-screened iPhone 5S. I can override `supportedInterfaceOrientations` but is there a better way to detect the 6 Plus screen other than specific checks like screen bounds or device model?

I looked into size classes, but couldn’t find a way to detect if a device returns `UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular` on Landscape orientation before the device is actually rotated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm supporting iOS 7 too so I've stuck with checking the screen scale > 2 but if you are on iOS 8 you can use the trait collection. The 6+ in landscape is "regular" width while other iPhones are "compact" width.

See the Apple [What's New](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-DontLinkElementID_1) doc for more info